# Hibernate ManyToMany on itself incorrect mapping

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have an entity : Volunteer which reference itself with @ManyToMany association :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Volunteer {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Volunteer.class)
    @Size(message = "Two valid partners maximum", max = 2)
    private Set<Volunteer> validPartners = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Volunteer.class, mappedBy = "validPartners")
    @Size(message = "Two valid partners maximum", max = 2)
    private Set<Volunteer> validPartnersOf = new HashSet<>();

}
```

When I save a Volunteer, mapping is only done on 1 side. When I list my volunteers, validPartners is visible on the entity I saved with a validParner.

At first I didn't put validPartnersOf. The mapping didn't work either. Hibernate need a "mappedBy" to make a correct mapping so I added it.

In the database, the join is well done, what did I do wrong ?
[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUCRB.png)

I also tried with @JoinTable on one of the fields :

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Volunteer.class)
@Size(message = "Two valid partners maximum", max = 2)
@JoinTable(
        name = "volunteer_valid_partners",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "volunteer_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "valid_partners_id"))
private Set<Volunteer> validPartners = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Volunteer.class, mappedBy = "validPartners")
@Size(message = "Two valid partners maximum", max = 2)
private Set<Volunteer> validPartnersOf = new HashSet<>();
```

[Here a screenshot of the result once I set validPartners for one of the Volunteers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbg84.png)

Comment: You are not specifying the `@JoinTable` and its `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns`; so your database must have a join table conforming to the JPA defaults. What does that table look like?

Comment: @BrianVosburgh: This must be a school holiday task, spent an hour yesterday on a very similar question with exact same class names :-)

Comment: @BrianVosburgh I tried  JoinTable with only "validPartners" and with both "validPartners" and "validPartnersOf"(I can only put JoinTable on one of them due to mappedBy)
and it didn't work either. I can't send image of database but it's generated by JPA so pretty basic